# Redis key - value versioning of value

Tags: redis

If I use Redis as key - value storage and update value several time with the same key. Can I retrieve previous version of value. 
For example change value 5 time but retrieve version that was on 3 update

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be able to do this by crawling the AOF file for changes to that key, but there isn't anything supported in Redis to get historical values for keys.

Comment: Since the AOF file might be rewritten, you CANNOT depend on that, i.e. the old version data might be deleted from the file.